# UIManager initialization takes a very long time - Any way around it?

Tags: java, performance, swing

In my standard Java Swing apps, I setup standard fonts, borders, colors, etc. via the various UIManager.put methods.

I noticed my UI apps were taking upwards of 10 seconds to startup and managed to trace it down to the first UIManager.put.  The first call apparently initializes the L&F.  Once initialized, things are reasonable.

Here is a perfect example (i.e. you don't even need to instantiate a UI to see it):

```
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class SlowUIManagerPut {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Font font = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10);
        long startingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.printf("1st UIManager.put: %d\n", System.currentTimeMillis() - startingTime);
    
        UIManager.put("Button.font", font);
        
        System.out.printf("Done with 1st.  2nd UIManager.put: %d\n", System.currentTimeMillis() - startingTime);
        
        UIManager.put("TextField.font", font);
        
        System.out.printf("Done with 2nd: %d\n", System.currentTimeMillis() - startingTime);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a work-around or some way to speed it up?

BTW:  It isn't my machine.  I'm running on a Dell Precision 7730 with hexacore I9, 64GB ram and 2TB SSD (M2 NVME) disk space.

Comment: I have never noticed a 10 second lag time to display a frame. I get 127ms and 128ms for the two outputs. I use JDK11 on Windows 10.

Comment: OK.. but are you invoking UIManager.put for anything you want to set?  And, are you saying you're getting those two times in the outputs for the program posted here?

Comment: Yes, I tested your code. That is the point of including an [mre] with the question. So we can see exactly what you are doing and test if required. I don't see a problem with the code other than code that changes the state of a GUI should be executed on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). However, even though you don't do this I still don't notice a problem, so maybe it is an OS/Java version that is causing the problem?

Comment: Interesting.  I'm developing on Ubuntu Linux Desktop, but using JDK11 as well.   Can we assume Java is optimized in some way for Windows, or, is Ubuntu's UI peer just slow?

Comment: Ten seconds are a horribly long time. This is definitely worth digging deeper to find out what exactly the initialization code is doing. Normally, all environments start with the same, system independent look & feel (i.e. Metal) on all platforms. There must be something odd in your environment. Considering the long time, the most likely issue is a dependency to a resource on a network drive in your setup (e.g. within `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`). And the drive is not available and the system configured to wait 10s whether it becomes available. Really, it’s hard to imagine anything that slow on its own.

Comment: "Ten seconds are a horribly long time."  My thoughts exactly.  I think I upset the create camickr because I alluded to him running the program I posted.  It was more in disbelief as his numbers were a quarter of a second, and mine is 40 times longer than that.

Comment: I traced the code in UI Manager down to where it does the initialization, but no farther, as it was clear somewhere down there is where my delay is, and only on the first put.